# foreach function only one shows

Tags: php, xml, parsing, foreach

New to PHP so don`t be mad if the question is really stupid.

i have made this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
img {float: left; margin-right: 30px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
</style>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
// specify url of xml file
$url = "http://travelplaza.ro/turcia/belek/Belek.xml" ;
// get xml file contents
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

// loop begins
foreach ($xml->hotel[0] as $hotel) {
echo $hotel["hotelname"];
echo "&nbsp";
echo $hotel["stars"];
echo "<p>";
echo $hotel->description . "</br>";
echo "</p>";
echo "<p>";
echo "</p>";
}
foreach ($xml->hotel[0]->images[0] as $i) {
echo '<a href="' . $i["url"] . '" rel="lightbox"><img src="' . $i["url"] . '" width="100"     height="100">';
echo "</a>";
```

}

Above is the xml itself..of course there are many hotels.
The result that i want is to have the title, description and pictures from the feed for the first hotel , then the second one and so on.
Instead i get only the images. If i remove the atributes [0] it gives a list with al the hotels with name , description and pics. Where is my mistake? I just want to show the hotel,description and the images. Any help would be apreciated. 
Thank you.
EDIT: If i want to show only hotel[45] with description and images ?

the xml looks like so :

```
<hotels>
<hotel hotelcode="xxx">
<description>
 bla bla
 </description>
 <images>
 <image url="http"/>
 </images>
 </hotel>
```

The above repeats and on the last one i have the  end tag.
The xml file is like this:
    http://travelplaza.ro/turcia/belek/Belek.xml

Comment: Please format your code, thanks.

Comment: @birgire The guidelines of this place clearly state that all relevant information must be contained inside the question. URLs to off site information are not permitted. They are a security thread to users trying to help.

Comment: @arkascha While I grant that inline examples are to be encouraged, it's pretty trivial to download an XML file without risking your security.

Comment: @IMSoP Certainly true, that would be possible. But why force everyone who tries to help download that file? Why not post it _once_ for all to see? I think it makes sense to point this out to the OP.

Comment: @arkascha Sure. You could perhaps have worded it more as a request though, rather than implying that it's breaking the rules. I would see it as more of a question quality issue than "not permitted".

Comment: @IMSoP You are certainly correct. Thanks for telling me and correcting my behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hotel[0]` means the first hotel in the list; when you loop over that, SimpleXML assumes you want its children. In this case, each hotel has two children, one `description` and one  `images`.

You want each hotel in turn, that is, all the elements called `hotel` so remove the [0]:

```
foreach($xml->hotel as $hotel)
```

For the images, you want to get them at the same time as the name and description, but you have two separate  loops, so you don't start looking at images until you've displayed all the descriptions.

Move the image loop inside the main loop, and change it to look at whichever hotel you're currently examining. Again, you don't want the [0], but looking at the XML there are multiple `image` elements inside one `images` element, so you need this:

```
foreach($hotel->images->image as $i)
```

(The [0] in this case sort of works as well, because $hotel->images[0] is the first and only `images` element, and its children are the individual `image` elements. I think the above better shows your intention.)

Comment: yes hotel[0] is the first element. The thing is that i am trying to get the description and the images for hotel[0], then in another file for hotel[1] and so. I must make some iframes and i just want to use one xml file.

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear from the question, but in that case you don't need the first loop at all - just write `$hotel = $xml->hotel[0];` and then the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't post the content of that xml file we can only *guess* its content...

Most likely `$xml->hotel` is an array of hotels. However you iterate over the frist element in that, not over the list of hotels. Try this instead:

```
foreach($xml->hotel as $hotel)
```

For the images: most likely you have to place the second foreach loop addressing the images *inside* the first loop, since each hotel most likely can hold references to several images. So the second loop should look something like this:

```
foreach($hotel->images as $i)
```

So the final code probably is meant to be like this:

```
$url = "http://travelplaza.ro/turcia/belek/Belek.xml";   
// get xml file contents
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

// loop over the hotels
foreach($xml->hotel as $hotel){  
  echo $hotel["hotelname"]."&nbsp".$hotel["stars"]."\n";
  echo "<p>\n".$hotel->description."\n</p>\n";

  // loop this hotels images
  echo "<p>\n";
  foreach($hotel->images as $image) {
    echo '<a href="'.$image["url"].'" rel="lightbox">'."\n";
    echo '<img src="'.$image["url"].'" width="100" height="100">'."\n";
    echo "</a>"\n;
  }
  echo"</p>\n";
}
```

But as said: without more details we can only *guess*...

Comment: personally, i think he needs a for loop instead. he could count the # of keys in the array and iterate through it, properly displaying all the images for each hotel. just my opinion.

Comment: That obviously depends on the contents of the xml file which is not known. But considering that it is xml I'd say it is more likely that the images are tags inside the hotel definition.

Comment: The question includes a public URL for the source XML, so no guessing is needed.

Comment: @IMSoP please read my comment about that below the question itself.

Comment: @arkascha It's still not true that you can *only* guess; you would just rather guess than download the external file. Your choice, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://travelplaza.ro/turcia/belek/Belek.xml";   
// get xml file contents
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
// loop begins
foreach($xml->hotel as $hotel) {
echo <<<EOD
<div>
  <p>{$hotel['hotelname']}</p>
  <p>{$hotel['stars']};</p>
  <p>{$hotel->description}</p>
  <p>
EOD;
  foreach ($hotel->images[0] as $i) {
  echo <<<EOD
  <p>
        <a href="{$i["url"]}" rel="lightbox"><img src="{$i["url"]}" width="100"     height="100">'</a>
  </p>
EOD;
  }
  echo <<<EOD
 </div>
EOD;
}
?>
```